# How can I change the model without having to delete the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

If I make any change in the model, now I have to delete and recreate the database. What do I resolve?

Comment: can you post code, controller(action)

Comment: How is this related to C? Did you mean [tag:c#]?

Comment: This is not about ASP.NET MVC, is it? It's Entity Framework...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in database manually.
Make sure you have `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation` unchecked in Options under Designers in SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

Comment: I removed the [Required] model in a field, put in the database this field to accept null, this message appears:                               The model backing the 'RequestContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

Comment: Can you explain how to use this tip?
What do I do after applying?
What should I do if I need to change a model, step by step?

Comment: You don't want to use the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy in a production environment

Comment: To change the structure of the tables in the database, you right click on the desired table and select design. From there you just make your needed changes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the alterations to the database manually.

There are automated tools to help you with reflection such as http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87 or http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

Comment: But how do I do that? If I change the type of the field he tells me to delete the database, and even a change in database error occurs.